# A set of formulas that classifies two-element structures

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Give a set of formulas $\Gamma$ such that for any structure $\mathcal{A}=\langle A;-;-\rangle$ it holds that $\mathcal{A} \models \Gamma$ if $A$ has **exactly** two elements.

Comment: What are the blanks in $\langle A; -; - \rangle$ there for? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Clive: Presumably these places are there to provide interpretations of function and predicate symbols, but since the sought $\Gamma$ must work in _any_ structure it can't mention any of those symbols anyway. One needs to assume that "$=$" is a logical primitive that doesn't need to be specified explicitly by the structure, though.

Comment: @Henning: Ah, I see. For a moment I thought it might mean $\mathcal{A}$ has two [constant/function/relation] symbols.

Comment: I have been thinking of introducing three variables, $x,y$ and $z$.  $\exists x \exists y \forall z (z \dot{=} x \lor z \dot{=} y \land x \dot{\not =} y)$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad what I wanted to write was $\exists$ for x andy y.

Comment: @user100561: Now you've edited it, that formula works (but it has ambiguous brackets).

Comment: How could I make it less ambiguous?

Comment: @user100561: See my answer. (I posted it as an answer rather than a comment so that this question doesn't appear as 'unanswered'.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you mention the comments works, but should be parenthesised as follows:
$$\exists x \exists y \forall z ((z=x \vee z=y) \wedge x \ne y)$$
It says there are two elements which are not equal such that any element is one or the other... which is precisely the statement that there are exactly two elements.

In general it's not true that $(A \vee B) \wedge C \equiv A \vee (B \wedge C)$, and without including parentheses it's unclear which of these $A \vee B \wedge C$ is taken to mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!